# onLongPress PaginatedDataTable DataRow

Tags: flutter, datatable, paginateddatatable

What is the best way to have an entire row trigger a callback when Long Pressing anywhere in it. Im using a `PaginatedDataTable`, which contains `DataRow`'s of `DataCell`'s.

The only way I found was by adding a `TableRowInkWell` or `GestureDetector` inside each `DataCell` but this doesn't work right, you need to actually long press on the text inside any of the cells to work.

Ive also tried adding padding to enlarge the selection area but that messed up the datatable itself.

```
      dataCells.add(DataCell(
        TableRowInkWell(
          onLongPress: () {
            // do something
          },
          onTap: () {
            // do something
          },
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 150),
            child: Text(
              content,
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              maxLines: 1,
              softWrap: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
```

Also `DataRow.byIndex` doesn't have any callbacks other than `onSelectChanged` which works for `onTap`.

```
   return DataRow.byIndex(
        onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
          // do something
        },
        index: index,
        cells: dataCells
    );
```